# Как рекурсивно обработать данные

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, рекурсия, дерево

Имеется данные в бд

```
 Id       Parent_id      Name
 1         0             Обувь
 2         1             Мужская
 3         1             Женская
 4         1             Детская
 5         4             Летняя/Зимняя 
 6         5             Кожаная/не кожаная/совсем не кожаная
 7         6             Китайская/не китайская/японская
```

Как обработать такие данные что создать дерево например в том же JS или PHP?
Хочу добиться вот такой вложенности:

```
Обувь--- Мужская
         Женская
         Детская
           |
           |----- Летняя/Зимняя               
                   |
                   |---- Кожаная/не кожаная/совсем не кожаная
                          |
                          |--Китайская/не китайская/японская
```

Comment: Не, а собсно в чём проблема? Получить данные? придумать, в каком виде их получить, чтобы было удобно отображать? собственно отобразить их?

Comment: Оптимально имхо рекурсивным CTE получить все записи, отсортированные по полному квалифицированному пути.

Comment: я немогу придумать алгоритм этой "сортировки"

Comment: Какая вложенность предполагается? я в том плане, что вложений может скольугодно много?

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: На вход массив объектов? Что на выходе? Объект?

Comment: Я ж сказал - построить полный путь. Скажем, для `"Обувь"` это будет `1`, а для `"Летняя/Зимняя"` соответственно `1/4/5`. Сортировка по такому полю даст именно требуемый порядок. Само собой все значения должны быть выровнены ведущими нулями до одинаковой длины.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь, пришел к таком решению

```
function build_tree(cats,parent_id, only_parent = false){
    let tree = []
    if(Array.isArray(cats) && cats[parent_id]){
        if(!only_parent) {
            cats[parent_id].map(function (cat, loli){
                tree.push(<TreeItem nodeId={parent_id+'.'+cat['id']} label={cat['name']}>
                    {build_tree(cats, cat['id'])}
                </TreeItem>);
            })
        }
    }
    return tree
}
```